# PIRLS step halving with cloglog link in lme4

Tags: optimization, precision, lme4

I'm getting the PIRLS step-halving error using `lme4::lmer()` with `family = binomial(link = cloglog)`. Seems possible to me that I've generated data for which the model below is too complex, which may be the full answer, but I don't understand the error note well enough to be confident. I saw another [answer that referenced behavior of less-canonical link function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37548423/8400969), and wondered if there could be issues in the machinery leading to this error as well/instead.

data, using dput:

```
sub <- structure(list(sp = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
                             "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", 
                             "5", "5", "5", "5"), rplct = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", 
                                                            "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X1", 
                                                            "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), abundance = c(131L, 
                                                                                                                                 124L, 128L, 114L, 108L, 62L, 57L, 62L, 65L, 54L, 45L, 45L, 35L, 
                                                                                                                                 38L, 33L, 29L, 31L, 30L, 32L, 30L, 21L, 20L, 25L, 23L, 28L), 
                      pres = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                               1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), tot_ab = c(288L, 277L, 280L, 
                                                                      272L, 253L, 288L, 277L, 280L, 272L, 253L, 288L, 277L, 280L, 
                                                                      272L, 253L, 288L, 277L, 280L, 272L, 253L, 288L, 277L, 280L, 
                                                                      272L, 253L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                            -25L))
```

No errors fitting a model with random effects but no offset term:

```
no_off <- lme4::glmer(pres ~ (1|sp)
                       , family = binomial(link = cloglog)
                      , data = sub)
```

Nor with offsets but no random effect:

```
no_re <- glm(pres ~ offset(log(tot_ab)) 
                             , family = binomial(link = cloglog)
                             , data = sub)
```

but PIRLS halving error with both offset and REs

```
smaller <- lme4::glmer(pres ~ offset(log(tot_ab)) + (1|sp)
               , family = binomial(link = cloglog)
               , data = sub)
```

What's driving this error in this example?

I was able to generate other interesting and more parseable errors, such as `Error: cannot generate feasible simplex` when simulating inappropriate data, not sure what my problem is here though.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused, this seems non-reproducible. (1) I think your link needs to be specified as a string (`link = "cloglog")` ? (2) the subset of data you provide has only a single value for the response, which throws a "Response is constant" error ...  Is this a subset of a large data set? Can you use `simulate()` to generate a reproducible data set? (I think the problem stems from the extremely thin tails of the inverse link function, but it will be easier to investigate with a reproducible example ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is fundamentally caused by the thin upper tail of the cloglog inverse-link function, which interacts with the default starting values for the parameters; fixed-effect coefficients are set to zero by default, random-effects (scaled) variances are set to 1 by default. This usually makes sense, but here's why it doesn't work when we have a large offset and a cloglog link:

```r
cc <- make.link("cloglog")$linkinv
par(las=1, bty = "l")
curve(1-cc(x), from = -5, to = 10, log = "y", n= 501,
          ylab = "1-Prob(x)", xlab = "Linear predictor")
```

[image]

Thus *any value of the linear predictor greater than about 3.6* will give a constant value of `1-.Machine$double.eps`.

If all of the offsets are significantly above 3.6 (i.e. total abundance greater than approx `exp(3.6)` = 36.6), then all of the predicted values will be on the upper 'shelf'; furthermore, the *gradient* of the inverse link function is zero in this region too, although R sets it to `.Machine$double.eps` in the region where it would likely [underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow).

It's not immediately obvious why this should break the PIRLS algorithm; it does depend on the derivative (see equation 13 [here](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/misc/glmer_JSS/glmer.pdf), but this equation isn't *obviously* broken by the scenario described here. (The inverse variance used in the weight matrix would be large, of order `1/.Machine$double.eps`, but again, this isn't necessarily a problem.

```r
library(lme4)
simfun <- function(seed = NULL) {
    if (!is.null(seed)) set.seed(seed)
    dd <- data.frame(sp = factor(rep(1:30, each = 5)),
                     tot_ab = rnbinom(150, mu = 250, size = 50))
    dd$pres <- suppressMessages(simulate(~ (1|sp) + offset(log(tot_ab))
                      , family = binomial(link = "cloglog")
                      , newdata = dd
                      , newparam = list(beta=-8, theta = 1))[[1]])
    dd
}
```

**Solution**: make the starting value for the intercept (the only fixed effect parameter in this example) much smaller, so that the starting values of the predictions are in a more reasonable range:

```r
glmer(pres ~ (1|sp) + offset(log(tot_ab)),
      family = binomial(link = "cloglog"),
      data = dd,
      start = list(fixef = -log(min(dd$tot_ab))))
```

The fit works (although we do get some convergence warnings).

It **might** work to define one's own `cloglog` link function that set the floor and ceiling differently, but this might just run into other numerical problems...

An alternative solution: rather than use log of total abundance as the offset, use `log(tot_ab)/min(tot_ab)`; that is, rather than model the probability of occurrence *per individual organism sampled*, model the occurrence of probability *in a sample the size of the minimum sample*. (You should also be able to pick a round number of the same order of magnitude as the smallest sample size.) The code below demonstrates that in 1000 runs on simulated data, the fit always fails with `offset(log(tot_ab))` but always succeeds (although there may be singular fits, convergence warnings, etc.) with the minimum-scaled offset.

```
fitfun <- function(dd, fix_offset = FALSE) {
    if (!fix_offset) {
        form <- pres ~ (1|sp) + offset(log(tot_ab))
    } else {
        form <- pres ~ (1|sp) + offset(log(tot_ab)/min(tot_ab))
    }
    res <- try(
        suppressMessages(
            glmer(
                form
              , family = binomial(link = "cloglog")
              , data = dd)), silent = TRUE
    )
    if (!inherits(res, "try-error")) return("OK")
    as.character(res)
}
```

Fit with original offset:

```r
set.seed(101)
res <- replicate(1000, fitfun(simfun()))
table(res)
```

```
Error : (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
                                                                                     8 
                                            Error : cannot generate feasible simplex
                                                                                   983 
                          Error : pwrssUpdate did not converge in (maxit) iterations

                                                                                     9
```

Now fit with min-scaled offset:

```r
res <- replicate(1000, fitfun(simfun(), fix_offset = TRUE))
table(res)
```

```
res
  OK 
1000
```

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker for writing a clean simulation, for the initial rescaled offset suggestion, and for this improved answer that sketches the problem clearly and provides what seems like a more general solution to helping ensure acceptable starting fixed effect parameter values!

Comment: I played with this with some data and the rescaled offset hasn't failed yet, but `start=list(fixef = -log(min(dd$totab)))` has a few times. Not yet to a minimal reproducible example of that, but will post when ready.